# Jacobian determinants in thermodynamics and a different approach to deriving the Maxwell relations

Tags: thermodynamics

In a PV diagram, the area enclosed by the Carnot cycle represents the work done by the system. Let's denote this area as $A_{\text{PV}}$. In a TS diagram, the area enclosed by the Carnot cycle represents the heat transferred during the cycle. Let's denote this area as $A_{\text{TS}}$.

The area under those graphs for the same Carnot cycle are same.

The equality of areas can be expressed as:

$$A_{\text{PV}} = A_{\text{TS}}.$$

### **Question 1:**

Does this have to do anything with the "Mechanical equivalent of heat"? The fact that in the heat and work can be interchanged and so much that in an ideal cycle that they can be totally transformed one to another (they even have the same SI unit, Joule).

### **Question 2:**

If you imagine the changing from the $PV$ diagram to the $TS$ diagram as an transformation from one coordinate system to another than you can use the Jacobian determinant. Now, let's consider the Jacobian determinant for the transformation between PV and TS variables:

$$ J = \frac{\partial(P,V)}{\partial(T,S)} = 1$$

Since the areas on both diagrams are the same, we can express the equality of areas in terms of the Jacobian determinant:

$$ A_{\text{PV}} = A_{\text{TS}} \Rightarrow J \cdot d(T,S) = d(P,V).$$

I heard that you can somehow from here derive the Maxwell relations and you don't have to use the Fundamental relation:

$$\mathrm{d}U = T\,\mathrm{d}S - P\,\mathrm{d}V.$$

Could someone help me derive the Maxwell relations from where I stopped because I heard that there is a nice intuitive approach using the Jacobian?

Thank you.

Comment: Contrary to what you said "In a TS diagram, the area enclosed by the Carnot cycle " the area enclosed is the work done by the cycle. It does not matter what coordinates and coordinate transformation you use, exactly because of the Jacobian is 1. The meaning is the same: work, and this work is exactly equal to the absorbed entropy at the high temperature = rejected entropy at the low temperature and multiplied by the temperature gradient as said entropy is moved through the cycle reversibly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1**

Yes, you can derive this from the first law of thermodynamics. For a cyclic process $W=Q$, heat equals work. However, the equality $Q=A_{TS}$ and $W=A_{PV}$ relies on the fact that the transformation is reversible. Otherwise, you'll need to replace the equalities by inequalities. In the case of heat, you have Clausius inequality: $Q<A_{TS}$. It is therefore not enough to conclude in the general case.

For an irreversible cycle, even if $Q\neq A_{TS}$ and $W\neq A_{PV}$, you still have equality of the areas. This is thanks to:
$$
dU = TdS-PdV
$$
which is always true. If you are familiar with hamiltonian mechanics, this shows that the transformation from the $PV$ plane to the $TS$ plane is symplectic with $U$ the generating function. In particular, it is area preserving, hence the equality.

**Question 2**

I'll assume you want to derive Maxwell's relations:
$$
\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_S = -\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial S}\right)_V
$$

To prove its equivalence to area preservation, you just need Green's theorem:
$$
\begin{align}
A_{TS}-A_{PV} &= \oint TdS-PdV \\
&= \int\left[\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_S +\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial S}\right)_V\right]dV\wedge dS
\end{align}
$$

Therefore, the areas are equal far all loops iff the integral is null everywhere, i.e. Maxwell's relation is verified.

Here is a second method involving an explicit computation of the Jacobian. The Jacobian of the transformation is:
$$
J = \left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_S\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\right)_T-\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_S\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial S}\right)_T
$$
To link it with Maxwell's relations, it is best to switch to $V,S$ reference variables. From the general formulas:
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\right)_T &= -\frac{\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial S}\right)_V}{\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_S} & \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_S &= \frac{1}{\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_S} \\
\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial S}\right)_T &= \left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial S}\right)_V+\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}\right)_S\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\right)_T & \left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_S &= \left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}\right)_S\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_S \\
&= \frac{\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial S}\right)_V\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_S-\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}\right)_S\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial S}\right)_V}{\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_S} & &= \frac{\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}\right)_S}{\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_S}
\end{align}
$$
So:
$$
\begin{align}
J &= \left[\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_S\right]^{-2}\left[-\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial S}\right)_V\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}\right)_S- \left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial S}\right)_V\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_S+\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}\right)_S\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial S}\right)_V \right] \\
&= -\frac{\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial S}\right)_V}{\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_S}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore $J=1$ iff you have Maxwell's relations.

Btw, these two proofs show that conservation of area is equivalent to the Maxwell's relations. If you are unfamiliar with symplectic transformations, I'll prove the claim in question 1, by the usual proof that Maxwell's relations are equivalent to the existence of $U$. From Maxwell's relations, using:
$$
\oint TdS-PdV = 0
$$
so this defines a state function:
$$
U(S,V) = \int_{(S_0,V_0)}^{(S,V)}TdS-PdV 
$$
with $(S_0,V_0)$ fixed and integral taking any path between the two endpoints. $U$ is well defined since the integral is independent of the chosen path, the difference being a loop which is $0$. The converse is obtained simply by Schwartz' theorem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Very informative. It helped a lot and also opened up some new questions. ;) Would up vote but still don't have the rep.

Comment: In which sense $dU=-PdV+TdS$ always true? As you write, it seems that one could use that relation for irreversible transformations.

Comment: $dU = \delta Q-\delta W=TdS-pdV$ but the individual terms do not match, unless the transformation is reversible. Since they do for reversible processes (which can be used to link any two infinitesimally close states) and involve state variables, the differential form is always true.

Comment: what I think @GiorgioP is hinting at is that while $dU=-pdV+TdS$ can be true for an irreversible process the equation is true only when the process connects two equilibrium states, and this you may wish to spell out explicitly. But, in reality, for a *finite* not an infinitesimal process that can be described by this differential form will have to be quasi-static because every infinitesimal step in it is an equilibrium one and if the process is such that quasi-static *is* reversible then two are the same, and only then.

Comment: Yes that is a nice observation. One more thing crossed my mind. This part of the answer: $\begin{align}
A_{TS}-A_{PV} &= \oint TdS-PdV \\
&= \int\left[\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_S +\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial S}\right)_V\right]dV\wedge dS
\end{align}$ reminded me of the proof of the Cauchy-Goursat theorem where we also use something to replace the part of the integrand to obtain zero, namely the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Do you thing there is a connection between the Maxwell relations and the CR equations or is it just a silly observation?

Comment: In the method yes, but for the CR’s, Maxwell’s relations give only one of the two. This is reassuring, since you don’t expect the variables to be harmonic functions, on the contrary,  they become singular when dealing with phase transitions.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 Yes I am considering quasi-static transformations (but not necessarily reversible), in general, it is tricky to talk about infinitesimal processes outside of these considerations. Thanks for clearing it up hyportnex.

Comment: Take my upvote; just a nitpick: you could have chemical potential and other irritating terms coming in. Only in the specific Carnot cycle do you get this equality.

Comment: Thanks. I have another question. Can we somehow prove the Carnot's theorem from the fact that the areas in pV and TS diagrams are the same? I want to write it here, but it is too long for a comment. Perhaps I will write another question.

Comment: I saw that you posted a new question on the topic. I'll answer there if I get to it.